# Matplotlib rendering

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I am converting Matlab plotting code into Python Matplotlib plotting code. I noticed that the Matlab-produced graph is much sharper:

Matlab
[image]

MatplotLib

[image]

Notice how you can see the small gaps in between the lines in the Matlab code. I tried adjusting parameters in the Python code such as line width, but no avail. How can I produce the graph with the integrity of the Matlab one?

Comment: care to update with your code?

Comment: This is the only code relevant to the line itself: `ax.plot((x1, x2), (C[interval_num] + 0.1 *j, C[interval_num] + 0.1 *j), color = colors[j - 1], linewidth = 3, label = labels[j])`

Comment: @goodcow, put the code in the question, where it's easier to read. It also makes the question faster to grasp without having to look at the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It could be me but to be honest I find the `matplotlib` plot you produced much sharper. This only concerns the data points. Therefore, I'm guessing you're referring to the `ticks` and `xlabel` sharpness.

There are several things I would do to increase the sharpness:

- You can increase the `fontsize` of the `ticks` with the following line:

  ```
  ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)
  ```
- Set the `dpi` of the figure:

  ```
  fig.set_dpi(500)
  ```
- Save the figure using a higher `dpi` value:

  ```
  fig.savefig("Figure.png", dpi = 500)
  ```